# unix - pattern matching in file

Tags: regex, unix

so I have a file with the following:

```
username=jsmith
api=3434kjklj23j4l3kj4l34j3l4j
```

I would like to return using regular expression "jsmith" and "3434kjklj23j4l3kj4l34j3l4j"

I know the regular expression for it is:

```
(username=)(.*) > \2
(api=)(.*) > \2
```

however using grep or sed or awk.  I can't seem to figure out the way to use them without return the entire line.

How would you go about doing that with a commandline command?

Comment: Does api always follow username, or is their relationship more nuanced?

Comment: If there's a line `game=chess` appears in the file, do you want `chess` to appear in the output?  Does it matter which sequence the values appear in?  Are there ever more than two lines in the file?

Comment: yes api always follows user name.

Comment: would want just chess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the answer that worked on the macos and RHEl7.

```
awk -F= '$1=="username"{print$2}'  testfile.txt
awk -F= '$1=="api"{print$2}'  testfile.txt
```

testfile.txt

```
username=user1 
api=pass1  
  username=user2 
api =pass2
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk` is made for this task:

```
awk -F= '{print$2}' file
```

If the file has other entries, you can limit the output with a condition:

```
awk -F= '$1=="username"||$1=="api"{print$2}' file
```

Comment: Or use `$1 ~ /username|api/ { print $2 }`?

Comment: Yes, `$1~/^(username|api)$/{print$2}` to be precise.

Comment: Yup — anchors are relevant and I omitted them.

Comment: awk -F= '$1=="username"||$1=="api"{print$2}' file.txt  returns nothing

Comment: @Lacer It does work for me though. Perhaps your input contains some spaces before the `=`? Demo: https://tio.run/##Nck5CoAwEEDR3mMEWwudaaf1HikCZrKSRCzUqzsuYPPh8/TmRPqRSK3VlKiDUcfxvc5W7bnY2PrpFPmZuAbblu5hAgR07DxPwOjBvUEGj3yl3GyKVYaZbg

Comment: I copied and pasted the suggestion to the terminal and shows nothing. hmm it shouldn't matter running macOS mojave

Comment: running awk version 20070501

Comment: How about `api=string with = characters` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one using bash, PCRE and positive lookbehind (where supported):

```
$ grep -Po "((?<=^username=)|(?<=^api=)).*" file
jsmith
3434kjklj23j4l3kj4l34j3l4j
```

ie. output everything that is preceeded by `username=` or `api=` that start the lines.

And one in awk:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^(username|api)=/,""){print}' file
jsmith
3434kjklj23j4l3kj4l34j3l4j
```

ie. print lines where preceeding `^username=` or `^api=` are removed first.

Comment: thanks for this but the grep command gives an error.  Also how would you just extract the username=<.*> only

Comment: @Lacer: does your version of `grep` support PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions)?  If you do `grep --help`, does it mention the `-P` option?  If not, then the `grep` version won't work, but the Awk more or less works.

Comment: doesn't look like it grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: To get the username only, use: `awk 'sub(/^username=/,""){print}' file`

Comment: Sounds like you got some space in there. How about `awk 'sub(/^ *username *=/,""){print}' file`

Comment: odd.. I'm copying and pasting the command as typed above. still nothing returned

Comment: running awk version 20070501

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to see `chess` with the input `game=chess`, here some solutions without matching `username=` or `api=`

```
cut -d"=" -f2- file
# or 
sed -n 's/[^=]*=//p' file
```